# Como extrair informações de um cabeçalho HTTP com Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, redes, scrapy

Sabemos que, no protocolo HTTP, o fim do cabeçalho é indicado por “`\r\n\r\n`”. Exemplo:

[image: HTTP normal]

Pode ser que, por alguma razão, o cliente não envie o “`\r\n\r\n`” ao servidor (pode ser um ataque, por exempo):

[image: Header Incompleto]

Suponha que eu tenha uma captura de tráfego de rede no formato PCAP chamado dump.pcap. Posso lê-lo com o seguinte código Python:

```
import pyshark

pkts = pyshark.FileCapture('dump.pcap')
```

Eu gostaria de ler o arquivo dump.pcap (código acima) e depois disso, contar quantos pacotes têm o `\r\n\r\n` e quantos pacotes não tem o `\r\n\r\n`
É possível realizar isso em Python? Como eu poderia fazer?

Comment: Uma requisição sem a linha em branco não é uma requisição válida, acredito eu. O servidor manterá a conexão aguardando o resto dos cabeçalhos ou corpo da mensagem e finalizar com timeout se não recebê-los. Se mesmo assim esses dados são capturados no seu arquivo, você deverá fazer a busca pela primeira linha da mensagem para reconhecer onde outra mensagem se inicia.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss: exatamente! é um ataque sloworis (negação de serviço). Não entendi muito bem como fazer? teria como ajudar?

Comment: Eu tentaria montar a sequência dos pacotes TCP para conseguir as requisições HTTP completas. Depois disso, avaliar se tem as quebras de linha necessárias depois do último campo de Header HTTP e a próxima requisição HTTP. É fácil identificar o começo das requisições, pois elas todas iniciam com um verbo HTTP (GET, POST, HEAD, PATCH, ...), seguido de um path (`/xampp/`, como no seu exemplo).

Comment: @Bruno Coimbra : Poderia, por gentileza,mostrar um código Python? Não faço ideia de como fazer.

Comment: Você definiu bem o problema, mas não mostrou nada em termos de tentativa de resolução, fora carregar o arquivo (sequer leu um pacote). Minha sugestão é que você continue lendo a documentação do pyshark e tentando resolver até chegar ao problema que está contido na sua pergunta, e depois coloque o código aqui.

Answer (score 3):

Bom dia amigo,

Seu problema resumidamente é que você deseja contar quantos ocorrências desse padrão teve em suas mensagens, uma forma de você fazer essa verificação é utilizando REGEX.

Suponha que seus cabeçalhos possam ser convertidos em string e cada string sendo colocado como um item de uma lista, você terá que percorrer a lista procurando a ocorrência do quebra de linha. No caso com são 4 caracteres de new line(\r\n\r\n) basta verificar essa ocorrência.

```
import re

x = len(re.findall("[\s{4}]+", txt)) #qualquer ocorrencia dos 4 caracters
y = len(re.findall("[\s{4}]+", txt)) #ocorrencias apenas no final da string
```

A varável `x` terá a quantidade de ocorrências dos 4 caracteres seguidos em qualquer posição, e a variável `y` contará apenas no final da string.